# how to copy file if it is locked by another process

Tags: windows-7

I have some strange behaviour in Windows 7, I can't copy my file or folder if they are locked (some process is using them) how can I disable this feature?

Answer (score 5):

It’s not a feature, it’s how the file-system works and is normal behavior.

You can use [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/). When you run it, it will display what processes have open handles to the file, and you can click the drop-down in the lower-left corner and select Copy. Then you can choose a location to copy the file to.

If you cannot install it either, then you won’t have the convenience of the sell-extension, but can still use the portable version from the command prompt. You’ll have to extract the files and run the EXE from a command-prompt as so:

```
C:\Unlocker> unlocker.exe "c:\My Folder"
```

Comment: How does the unlocker work? Does it pause the process locking the file then copy it?

Comment: No. Unlocker uses a driver to get low-level access to the file, thus bypassing the access restrictions (the restriction being that the file is locked).

Comment: @Synetech , Is it possible to change locked file in low-level access?

Comment: @SEARAS, no, Unlocker only provides *Move*, *Copy*, and *Delete* access, not *Open* or *Save* access. It is conceivable that a program/driver could be written to allow that, but you would then be making the program that has it open unstable, which means it could crash, so you would just be better off closing the program anyway. (If you move or delete the file, you have to close the handle which also makes the program unstable; you can copy the file without closing the handle.)

Answer (score 0):

We are using a 3rd party command line [GS Copy Pro](http://www.gurusquad.com/Replication/GSCopyPro) since a long time to copy open/locked files. It supports VSS. It's very robust and reliable.

They have shared many video and example on their website to generate the dos batch script with simple GUI.